# I m using one database with the same name in SQL Server 2000 and SQL Server 2005

Tags: sql-server-2005, sql-server-2000, connection-string

I am using one database with the same name in SQL Server 2000 and SQL Server 2005.

How can I manage the connection string in the web.config file so that we can differentiate the connection.

While we are using the same user name and password for the both databases.

Comment: Assuming both are installed on the same server surely they are not both the default instance?  I didn't think it was possible to run both alongside each other with the same instance?

Answer (score 1):

They should have different server names, no?

[edit]
As per the comments, if the server name is the same it would have a different instance name or port. You can only have one default instance, after all

Comment: Or they could be the same server but seperate instances i.e.

Server1 and Server1/Sql2kInstance

Comment: Yes, instance name was really what I was looking for

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest that both install are running seperate instances if installed on the same server so just specify the instance name in your connection string.

so if one is the default Instance

```
Data Source=myServerAddress;Initial Catalog=myDataBase;User Id=myUsername;Password=myPassword
```

;

and a non default instance example

```
Data Source=myServerAddress\OtherInstance;Initial Catalog=myDataBase;User Id=myUsername;Password=myPassword;
```